# What species is this yellow flower of angiosperm from Morocco?

Tags: species-identification, botany

What species is this yellow flower of angiosperm from Morocco? I photographed it in spring. I estimate the diameter of a flower to be 1.5 cm. [image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's undoubtedly in the genus *Oxalis* but there are hundreds of species in this genus.  The genus name refers to the high content of oxalic acid found in this genus.